# Read excel file with Pyspark in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I've got this issue:

```
Failed to find data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I tried to install the package with pip but it displayed the message below:

```
Command 'pip install com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.1' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How can I solve this problem ?
I'm afraid that it could be related with my cluster permissions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Python library, but Maven coordinates of JVM library - it needs to be installed on the cluster level via UI or API - check [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html) for exact instructions.